# Fix wrong typosquatting warning in Google Chrome

Tags: domain-name, google-chrome

My client is running websites on 2 domains names. Let's say `companyname.com` and `company-name.com`.

He's clients recently started to receive this kind of warning on Google Chrome:

[image]

Sorry I only have it in French, but it basically say that the domain name is pretty similar to another one, and this could be a typosquatting attack.

I didn't find any documentation on this feature given that it has been released recently by Google Chrome.

Do you know if there is a way to make Chrome understand that the 2 domain names are provided by the same company, and so it's not a hack ?

PS: My client wants to keep 2 dedicated domains, so merging them and use subdomains is not an option for now.

Thank you

Comment: Why is your client wanting to keep separate content on these domains? This is confusing, and it is what has led Google to think that something is wrong.

Comment: "The site you just tried to visit looks fake. Attackers sometimes mimic sites by making small, hard-to-see changes to the URL."  - from `components/security_interstitials_strings.grdp`

Comment: Is either domain on the list of the compiled-in [more-important-than-you](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/url_formatter/spoof_checks/top_domains/domains.list) claims? If so, you might have to entirely opt out of that protection until you have buried the duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton because they are used to it... I tried to convince them to merge the domains, but no success yet.

Comment: @anx thanks, it could be a good start for investigating. Their domains are not part of the top-domains list that you sent.